# Se categoria existir adiciona no Menu - Woocommerce 3.6.4

Tags: php, funções, woocommerce

Estou a usar a hierarquia: Samsung>S9 Plus,Categoria A
O código só funciona no seguinte endereço: https://paginaweb.pt/categoria-produto/s9-plus

O código é este:

```
// adiciona produto ao menu se categoria existir
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'adiciona_produto_menu', 10, 2 );
function adiciona_produto_menu( $items, $args ) {
    // não funciona com a categoria samsung
    //if( has_term( 'samsung', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    if( has_term( 's9-plus', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $produto = '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">
                        <div class="nav-toggle-subarrow">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                            <span class="fontawesome-text">Produtos</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="fontawesome-text">Samsung</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>';
    }
    return $produto.$items;
}
```

**Pergunta:**
Se a categoria Samsung existir, pretendo adicionar ao Menu principal, mas não estou a perceber como. Será preciso usar a localização do Menu?

```
$args->theme_location == 'primary'
```

E porquê que só é apresentado na categoria S9 Plus... não entendo! Podem ajudar?

---

Ok, então será assim:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'adiciona_produto_menu', 10, 2 );
    function adiciona_produto_menu( $items, $args ) {

        if ( term_exists( 'apple', 'product_cat' ) ) :
            $apple = '<li style="border-top:0;border-bottom:0;" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="https://paginaweb.pt/categoria-produto/apple/" target="_self" rel="nofollow noopener"><span class="fontawesome-text">Apple</span></a></li>';
        endif;

        if ( term_exists( 'google', 'product_cat' ) ) :
            $google = '<li style="border-top:0;border-bottom:0;" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="https://paginaweb.pt/categoria-produto/apple/" target="_self" rel="nofollow noopener"><span class="fontawesome-text">Google</span></a></li>';
        endif;

        $categorias = '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><div class="nav-toggle-subarrow" target="_self" rel="nofollow noopener"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span class="fontawesome-text">Produtos</span></a><ul class="sub-menu">' . $apple . $google . '</ul></li>';
        return $categorias.$items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O termo correto é: `term_exists` ou seja, `if( term_exists( 'samsung', 'product_cat' ) )`

Comment: Só adicionando que `has_term()` é para verificar se um post tem certa categoria, e no caso para o que você pretende fazer, o correto é verificar se o termo existe na categoria com `term_exists()`.

Comment: @Claudio Sanches obrigado pelo seu comentário! Já agora, a onde é que posso encontrar mais informações sobre termos e outras informações? Ando sempre às aranhas nunca consigo encontrar documentação...

Comment: Documentação que eu uso é esta: https://developer.wordpress.org/, sei que não é muito, mas eu curto de pesquisar ai e ir estudando por ela, não sei se te ajuda, mas pode ser um começo.